# Android Studio - Unresolved reference often until (Kotlin or Composable plugin fails?)

Tags: android, android-studio

Very often I get the following errors when I try to build a project:

[image]

I noticed that it may happen often after:

- git rebase
- replacing some code lines in many files using CTRL+SHIFT+R

The code 100% is correct, there are no errors in Android Studio editor as well, no red lines, it fails only during building:

[image]

To fix the issue I can delete `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle` folder and it works normally again.

`Android Studio/File/Invalidate Cashes` doesn't help, only deleting `.gradle` folder and then I can build the project without any errors.

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10406996, built on June 29, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-b2043.56-10027231 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 11 10.0
```

It was happening with previous versions as well, still not fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess disabling the following Gradle options should fix i:

```
# Enable caching between builds.
org.gradle.caching=false

# Enable configuration caching between builds.
org.gradle.unsafe.configuration-cache=false
```

but also have to delete the following build cache folder as well:

`.C:\Users\USER_NAME\.gradle\caches\buildcaches(something likes this`